# ViewChildren with templateRef

Tags: angular, dom, angular8, viewchild

I want to use `ViewChildren` make `QueryList` from `TemplateRef`, but can't pass to input component.

For example

Component.ts:

```
@ViewChildren(TemplateRef) cellTemplates: QueryList<TemplateRef<any>>;
```

View:

```
<my-component [templatesRef]="cellTemplates"></my-component>
```

Input :

```
_templatesRef;
@Input()
set templatesRef(refs: any) {
   this._templatesRef = refs;
}
```

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed
>   after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: false'. Current value:
>   'ngIf: true'.

See in [Stackbilitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6hzjex)

Comment: Please provide your full code, not the code you think is relevant. Even better, provide a [mcve] reproducing your issue.

Comment: @Maryannah Yes that's right [Stackbilitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6hzjex) , thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should force parent to detect changes after getting the cellTemplates from template, so try to use ChangeDetectorRef in parent:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  @ViewChildren(TemplateRef, {read: TemplateRef}) cellTemplates: QueryList<TemplateRef<any>>;
  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
  ngOnInit(){ }
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.cd.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

You can find detailed explanations about that exception in this [article](https://indepth.dev/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error/).

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s2qnta)

Comment: Thanks, but there is a better solution `setter`

Answer (score 2):

An ugly work around is, in your app-component

```
<my-component *ngIf="yet" [templatesRef]="cellTemplates"></my-component>
```

Implements afterViewInit and use a setTimeout

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit  {
  yet=false;

  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.yet=true
    })
  }
}
```

The problem is that at first cellTemplates is a empty query and afterViewInit get elements,

Comment: Really I like your approach -detectChanges-, but i'm not sure (yet), thanks for the link. For me it's more natural give a "breath" to Angular than use detectChanges. let me give a turn it

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the view variable you created instead?

```
<my-component [templatesRef]="title"></my-component>

<ng-template #title>
    ok
</ng-template>
```

Comment: I have several templates, I need to get all the templates.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution without using `ChangeDetectorRef` & `setTimeout` .

```
@ViewChildren(TemplateRef, {read: TemplateRef})
set cellTemplates(refs: QueryList<TemplateRef<any>>) {
    this._cellTemplates = refs;
}
```